# Coupling of two discrete random variables (multiple outputs)

Tags: probability

Let U and V be random variables on $\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}_0$ with probability mass functions $f_U(x) = \frac{1}{2}1_{\{0,1\}}(x)$ and  $f_V(x) = \frac{1}{3}1_{\{0,1,2\}}(x)$, where $x\in \mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}_0$, $1_S$ is the indicator function of the set S. Give a coupling of $U$ and $V$ under which $\{U\geq V\}$ with probability $1$.

Note : Question is from exercise of "Probability Theory: The Coupling Method" by Frank den Hollander.

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question and tell us what have you tried so far, how did you try to tackle the problem or where you encountered difficulties.

Comment: I have tried by creating the matrix of U outcomes vs V outcomes and adjusting the probabilities such that P(U<V) = 0 that is for events (0,2) and (1,2) [(U,V) space]. But, was not able to do so by any method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have $U\ge V$ with probability $1$ because $P(V=2)=1/3$ and, $P(U<2)=1$. Therefore we have $U\ge V\implies V<2$ and $P(U\ge V)\le P(V<2)=2/3<1$.

However you can have $U\le V$ with probability $1$. Take for instance the random variable $W$ uniformly distributed on $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, or with your formulation, with probability mass function $f_W(x)=\frac161_{\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}}(x)$, and define:

- $U=0$ if $W\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $U=1$ if $W\in\{3,4,5\}$,
- $V=0$ if $W\in\{0,1\}$, $V=1$ if $W\in\{2,3\}$ and $V=2$ if $W\in\{4,5\}$.

This can be rewritten more compactly as

$U=\lfloor\frac W3\rfloor$ and $V=\lfloor\frac W2\rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you Will for explanation.